# Creating a dataframe with data extracted from a website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get the number of sharing from Facebook section using selenium as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

total = []
shares = []
comments = []
reactions = []
    
query=["www.stackoverflow.com","www.facebook.com"]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(mypath,chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get('https://www.sharedcount.com/')
textarea = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea')
for x in query:
     textarea.send_keys(query)
     button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button button_accent-green']")
     button.click()
     body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tb-data tb-data_face[@class='bold-text']")
     total.append(body)
     sharing=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tb-line-info__text tb-line-info__text_left tb-line-info__face[@class='bold-text']")
     shares.append(sharing)
     com=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tb-line-info__text tb-line-info__text_left[@class='bold-text']")
     comments.append(com)
```

creating a new dataframe with information for each url in the query list.
However, I'm getting this error

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tb-data tb-data_face[@class='bold-text'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//tb-data tb-data_face[@class='bold-text']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

Does anyone know how fix error and have the following output?

```
url                       shares         comments         reactions 
www.stackoverflow.com      11.2k           3.8k              9.1k
www.facebook.com         1920.4m           64.9m             517.7m
```

After using WebDriverWait I get this other error:

```
     24 button.click()
---> 25 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//td[@class="tb-data tb-data-face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]')))
     26 body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="tb-data tb-data-face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]')
     27 total.append(body)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the `<td>` and `<div>` tags in the XPath. It should be

`'//td[@class="tb-data tb-data_face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]'`

You also need to adjust the `sharing` and `com` XPaths using the same idea.

Edit 1:
Try to wait for the visibility of element:

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

```
for x in query:
     ...
     button.click()
     
     # Wait 10 seconds for the element to be visible
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//td[@class="tb-data tb-data_face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]')))

     body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="tb-data tb-data_face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]')
     total.append(body)
     ...
```

Comment: I replaced the line of code in the different fields as you suggested (similar line of code for sharing and com), but got this error: `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@class="tb-data tb-data-face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]"}`

Comment: My guess is that you need to wait the visibility of element. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you montovanelli. I have got a new error. I updated the question to show the new error after trying with WebDriverWait

Comment: It was a typo. Replace "td-data tb-**data-face**" by "td-data tb-**data_face**"

Comment: Ah, you also need to replace ```query=["www.stackoverflow.com","www.facebook.com"]``` by ```query=["www.stackoverflow.com", "\n", "www.facebook.com"]``` to correctly create a new line.

Comment: I am currently trying with just one website. I have tried to replace that and it has fixed the error message with the body. However, I am getting the same error message for the sharing. Can I ask you to have a quick look at this path? The error message is the following: `---> 28 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//td[@class="tb-line-info_text tb-line-info_text_left tb-line-info_face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]')))`. I guess I will have similar error also for the comments. Many thanksù

Comment: You need to check the correct xpath for sharing and comments. Inspecting the website I can see that for "sharing" it's `'//span[@class="tb-line-info__text tb-line-info__text_left tb-line-info_face"]/div[@class="bold-text"]'`. Try to construct the "comments" XPath yourself to practice the XPath construction. If you can't, you can ask, ok?

Comment: Fixed both. Thank you @montovanelli. The only problem is that I am not extracting values from those Xpath. An example of information stored in the list is: `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="87fd113ee0988130766e0b671199e84d", element="543b72d4-e676-4341-9e18-ec1a5779d820")>]` which actually does not make sense. Have I missed something? –

Comment: Yes. You are not extrating the text from elements. You want to use `.text` to extract the text. Example: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tb-data tb-data_face[@class='bold-text']").text`

Important note: As far as I know, `.text` extract only visible text. As I can see, some of the text you need are collapsed. In this case, you may use `.get_attribute('textContent')` to correctly extract the information.

Comment: Thank you, montovanelli, for all the help you provided. I forgot to include .text (thank you for pointing out!). I didn't think about the get_attribute for correctly extracting the info. Thanks a lot!